# Read/Write pandas DataFrame into MSSQL VarBinary(MAX) field using SqlAlchemy (or other)

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a pandas DataFrame loaded from a CSV file. I'd now like to serialise (INSERT) that dataframe into a varbinary(max) field and then deserialise (SELECT) it into a DataFrame object.

I've tried a number of approaches. I can successfully write to the DB using this code:

```
conn = pymssql._mssql.connect(server='localhost', user='user', password='user', database='db')
bytes = df.to_records().tobytes()
buf = '0x' + binascii.hexlify(bytes).decode('ascii')
sql = f"INSERT INTO bin_prices (ticker, data) VALUES ('{ticker}', CAST({buf} AS VARBINARY(MAX)))"
conn.execute_non_query(sql)
```

The problem is deserialisation. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried just pickling the DataFrame? [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/5d0e97a4622ea4a2edc83c108d9a03dd) seems to work fine for me.

Comment: You've nailed it Gord, thank you! Just one side note - I had to append "?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server" to my connection string to get the SqlAlchemy engine to write the data. I'm using version "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)". Hopefully this detail hopes somebody else. Much appreciated